# Access local web files via Microsoft Edge extension

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, local-files, microsoft-edge-extension

Recently we migrated a Chrome extension to Microsoft Edge. We face only one problem. Extension should interact with webpages, that works fine with online webpages but not with local files.

Chrome offers for this situation permission called `<all_urls>`. We tried to use `<any url>` permission that we found on Microsoft support page, but without any result. We would like to interact with any webpage, not specific one.

Does Edge support this functionality - and if it does, how can we achieve it?
If not, is it planned in near future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, local file access can be achieved by checking `Allow access to file URLs` in `chrome://extensions`, however **this feature is not supported in Microsoft Edge at now**.

[image]

As for feature plan, you may want to provide your feedback in their [Feedback site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer).

Comment: Thanks, I know that this is the check, but you need to allow this checkbox in permissions. I tried to write it to Microsoft support but it redirected me to stackoverflow. (On their dev support page: Q & A site Stack Overflow is where we focus dev community discussions). Nevertheless, I will also provide it as feedback.